# How to remove a whole project from SVN synchronization?

Tags: php, eclipse, subclipse

I have a project i no longer want synchronised to SVN (as this is just a copy and i have another project synchronised)... How in the life do i remove it from SVN using Eclipse, or anything basically?

I can't see any .svn file in the directory folder.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on your project folder, and select Team>Disconnect (this is for subversive, it should be the same with subclipse).

Answer (score 0):

Export your project from SVN using:

> svn export repo_url

then replace files under eclipse with exported ones.

See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re10.html for details about export option

**Update:**
greg0ire's way seems to be much easier. Disconnect option is available under subclipse too.